# Rails Select form not updated on redirect

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps

I'm creating a site with reviews of cities (yay standard CRUD apps!), a form is populated with all available cities using the @cities_array instance variable. See my new method in reviews_controller:

```
  def new
    @review = Review.new
    @cities_array = City.cities_alphabetized
  end
```

A user visits the new_review_path, the form dropdown is populated with cities as it should be, all good. Form code:

```
<%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities_array) %>
```

On the same page, there's another form where a user can add a city if it's not in the dropdown. They type in the name, and there's an AJAX request sent to Google Geocoder that routes to my create cities method and makes the new city. Create method:

```
def create
    latitude = params[:latitude].to_f.round(4)
    longitude = params[:longitude].to_f.round(4)
    name = params[:name]
    city = City.new(name: name, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    if city.save
      flash[:success] = "City created! Please refresh."
      redirect_to new_review_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Your city couldn't be created."
      redirect_to new_review_path
    end
  end
```

You'll notice that if the new city is saved, the user gets redirected to the reviews page. However, my form with the dropdown of cities is not getting updated unless the user refreshes the browser manually.

Why is this form not getting refreshed after the redirect? I checked and my @cities_array is incrementing to include the new city, but why does the user have to refresh for the new city to show up in the form's dropdown?

Clearly I'm not understanding something there!

Here's the logs in case that's helpful:

```
Started POST "/cities" for ::1 at 2016-05-03 21:11:49 -0400
Processing by CitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Dong Hoi", "latitude"=>"21.0128173", "longitude"=>"107.45755380000003"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "cities" ("name", "latitude", "longitude", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Dong Hoi"], ["latitude", 21.0128], ["longitude", 107.4576], ["created_at", "2016-05-04 01:11:50.021635"], ["updated_at", "2016-05-04 01:11:50.021635"]]
   (0.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/reviews/new
Completed 302 Found in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 6.3ms)


Started GET "/reviews/new" for ::1 at 2016-05-03 21:11:50 -0400
Processing by ReviewsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  City Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "cities".* FROM "cities"
  Rendered reviews/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 442ms (Views: 176.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)
```

Comment: Does the exact same thing. My redirect is working, I don't think that's the problem. Just not sure why my form drop down isn't updating. Posting the logs in my question so people can see.

Comment: i think, u need to call it as ajax then. thats better solution

Comment: You mean populate the form with AJAX instead of using the the Rails form helper?

Answer (score 0):

I THINK what you need is to show the selected value after the form has been submitted.  Try this:

```
<%= f.select :city_id, options_for_select(@cities_array, selected: @review.city_id) %>
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not. At this point, a review isn't associated with a city yet since the user hasn't chosen a city to write a review for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was meaning about Ajaxing. Also Can you try this one, and let me know:

```
if city.save
  flash[:success] = "City created! Please refresh."
  @cities_array = City.cities_alphabetized
  render :new
else
  flash[:notice] = "Your city couldn't be created."
  redirect_to new_review_path
end
```